# Show duplicate legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a line graph for some bird count data. The counts were done on 2 islands, and the islands are split into regions. The colours of the lines show the region, and whether the line is dashed or solid shows the island.

The first graph that I produced had two legends, one for island (dashed vs solid line) and one for region (line colour). However, in the region legend, all lines were shown as solid lines, regardless of whether the line is actually solid or dashed. In my actual data I have about 20 regions, so it's difficult to tell the colours apart and to match the lines to the legend.

[image: 2 legends]

I worked out how to combine the legends into one, by setting colour and line type to be done by region, and then setting a manual scale for line type that corresponds to the islands. However, this is a bit of a risky workaround, as it depends on the regions being in the same order. If the order changes they will be drawn as being on the wrong island.

[image: 1 legend]

Furthermore, it is now impossible to see what the line type shows, that information is gone from the legend.

What I am looking to create is a graph like this (done in Paint):

[image: Ideal graph]

This shows the islands in the legend and has the true line style for the regions. Is it possible to make a graph like this? I have tried all sorts of workarounds without success. If possible, I would like to avoid manually coding the islands like I did to produce the second graph, as this is not good for future proofing the code and prone to mistakes.

Here is my code. Nb: The actual results are just filled in randomly, so the lines will be in different positions for each iteration.

```
mydata <- data.frame(Season=c("Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 4", "Year 4", "Year 4"),
                     Op_RegionName=c("Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4"),
                     Island=c("B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"),
                     Total=sample(0:5, 16, replace=TRUE))

regioncolours = c("#B5BDE7", "#B32F48", "#EB8423", "#517F3A")

# Show Op region and Island on different legends
mydata %>%
  group_by(Season, Op_RegionName) %>%
  add_count(wt=Total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Season, n, group=Op_RegionName, col=Op_RegionName, linetype = Island)) + # Note the difference in the linetype argument
  geom_line(linewidth=1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = regioncolours) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2)) +
  labs(linetype = "Island", colour="Operational Region") + # Set the legend titles here
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 1), colour = guide_legend(order = 2)) + # Set the order in which the legends appear
  xlab("Monitoring season") +
  ylab("No. of birds in 5-minute bird counts") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + # Removes the grey background
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + # Adds black axis lines
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) # Sets the y axis to start at 0

# Show op region and island together on the same legend
mydata %>%
  group_by(Season, Op_RegionName) %>%
  add_count(wt = Total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Season, n, group=Op_RegionName, col=Op_RegionName, linetype=Op_RegionName)) + # Note the difference in the linetype argument
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = regioncolours, name = "Operational Region\n and Island") + # Set the legend title here
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2,2,1,1), name = "Operational Region\n and Island") + # Manually choose which to have dashed (the last 4, South Island). Also set the legend title here
  xlab("Monitoring season") +
  ylab("No. of birds in 5-minute bird counts") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + # Removes the grey background
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + # Adds black axis lines
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA)) # Sets the y axis to start at 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the linetypes in the legend independently of the lines on the plot using `override.aes` in your `guides()`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- data.frame(Season=c("Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 4", "Year 4", "Year 4"),
                     Op_RegionName=c("Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4", "Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4"),
                     Island=c("B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"),
                     Total=sample(0:5, 16, replace=TRUE))

regioncolours = c("#B5BDE7", "#B32F48", "#EB8423", "#517F3A")

# Show Op region and Island on different legends
mydata %>%
  group_by(Season, Op_RegionName) %>%
  add_count(wt=Total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Season, n, group=Op_RegionName, col=Op_RegionName, linetype = Island)) + # Note the difference in the linetype argument
  geom_line(linewidth=1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = regioncolours) +
  labs(linetype = "Island", colour="Operational Region") + # Set the legend titles here
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 1), colour = guide_legend(order = 2, override.aes = list(linetype = c(4,4,1,1)))) + # Set the order in which the legends appear
  xlab("Monitoring season") +
  ylab("No. of birds in 5-minute bird counts") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + # Removes the grey background
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + # Adds black axis lines
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, this is still a somewhat 'bespoke' solution to the problem i.e. when you say "If possible, I would like to avoid manually coding the islands like I did to produce the second graph, as this is not good for future proofing the code and prone to mistakes.", you will still have this issue unfortunately, as you need to know how many lines you have and what their linetypes should be in order to specify them 'manually'.

Comment: Thanks Jared, this is amazing! Really appreciate you helping me with this.